# Raphael.js Animate the rotation of a path with a given center point

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I'm trying to animate triangle (think, needle of an angular gauge) such that it rotates at a given point (see the red dot).

```
var svg = Raphael("container",400,400),
    triangle = svg.path("M210 200L190 200L200 100Z").attr({fill:"#000"}),
    circle = svg.circle(200,200,5).attr({fill:"#f00"});

// to animate ??
triangle.animate({rotation:100,cx:200,cy:200},1000,'<>');
// doesn't work
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BS6j6/1/)

I can rotate (without animating) along that center fine:

```
// to rotate with center point 200,200, works fine
triangle.rotate(80,200,200);
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to animate the rotation such that it rotates around that point.  It always seems to rotate at the center of the path.

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
triangle.animate({rotation:"300 200 200"},1000,'<>');
```

Comment: amazing!  thanks so much, this isn't documented anywhere, how did you know that?

Comment: Most documentation is flawed, but you can always try (or read the real documentation which is the js source ;) You can also extend raphaël with your own custom format for animation, see http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#custom-attributes.

Comment: ya I often do go to the source, but the Raphael src is pretty cryptic, plus the minimal amount of comments makes it a bit hard to parse.  Thanks for the heads up on customAttributes, that will definitely help :)

Answer (score 24):

### Since Raphael.js version 2.0

#### To animate simple rotation you can use:

`yourTriangle.animate({transform: "r" + 15}, 2000);`

Where:

- `r` = rotation
- `15` = angle in degrees
- `2000` = time in milliseconds.

#### To animate rotation with given center point

You need to specify center coordinates:
`yourTriangle.animate({transform: "r60" + "," + centerX + "," + centerY}, 2000);`

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/S8Z93/)

So you have to use **string** as an object property: `{transform: "r15"}` or `{transform: "r15, centerX, centerY"}`.

Answer (score 4):

To rotate a path around a given point, e.g. the end of a line, use this:

```
rapahel.path.animate({transform: "r60,100,100"}, 1000, "<>");
```